# ES6 ajax callback plain javascript

Tags: ajax, ecmascript-6

I've got the following event listener to fire an ajax request, which works. I want to improve the callback functionality however.

```
const bindEvents = () => {
  const emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
  emailInput.addEventListener('blur', function(){
   const emailValue = emailInput.value
   isValidEmail('http://localhost:3001/user/email/'+emailValue, 'data_placeholder', console.log(' '))
  });
}
```

and the following AJAX call

```
const isValidEmail = (url, data, success) => {
  const xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xhr.open('POST', url);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText)
      NotInDatabase(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
  xhr.send(data);
  return xhr;
}
```

I'm firing the function NotInDatabase after xhr data is returned. Can someone clarify for me how to use the 'success' from isValidEmail? Is there a way to use the return xhr in the event listener where isValidEmail is called?

Thanks!

Comment: Just replace `NotInDatabase` by `success`, and pass `NotInDatabase` instead of `console.log(…)` in the call?

Comment: Are you saying NotInDatabase(xhr.responseText); needs to become success(xhr.responseText)?

Comment: Yes, that's what Bergi meant.

Comment: what should const isValidEmail = (url, data, success) =>  now look like? doesn't success here need to be a function? I can't seem to pass the data from isValidEmail('http://localhost:3001/user/email/'+emailValue, 'data_placeholder', NotInDatabase()) into the NotInDatabase function

Comment: @jj1111 `success` is a parameter variable to hold a function, yes. But of course you have to pass in the function `NotInDatabase`, instead of the result of the call to the function `NotInDatabase()`.